# Как сделать меню паузы в игре (Time.timeScale)?

Tags: unity3d

Обычно, пауза в игре делается через `Time.timeScale = 0f;`, и раньше я так и делал.

Меню паузы у меня находится на той же сцене. И когда я использовал в меню обычные кнопки - всё работало. Но мне потребовалось использовать анимацию (`DOTween`). И теперь у меня всё зависает, что не удивительно т.к. время = 0.

**Как сделать меню паузы в игре?**

PS
Может возможно сделать разный `Time.timeScale` для сцены и для меню на этой сцене?

Пробовал

```
GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().DOFade(1,animationDuration).SetUpdate(UpdateType.Late, true)
```

тормозит и глючит - работает через раз. Без `SetUpdate(UpdateType.Late, true)` не работает вообще.